# Cassandra query flexibility

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-spark, bigdata, cql

I'm pretty new to the field of big data and currently stucking by a fundamental decision.

For a research project i need to store millions of log entries per minute to my Cassandra based data center, which works pretty fine. (single data center, 4 nodes)

```
Log Entry
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Timestamp              | IP1         | IP2           ... 
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2015-01-01 01:05:01    | 10.10.10.1  | 192.10.10.1   ...
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each log entry has a specific timestamp. The log entries should be queried by different time ranges in first instance. As recommended i start to "model my query" in a big row approach.

```
Basic C* Schema
------------------------------------------------------------------
| row key              | column key a         | column key b     ... 
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2015-01-01 01:05    | 2015-01-01 01:05:01  | 2015-01-01 01:05:23
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*Additional detail: 
column keys are composition of timestamp+uuid, to be unique and to    avoid overwritings;
log entries of a specific time are stored nearby on a node by its identical partition key;*

Thus log entries are stored in shorttime intervals per row. For example every log entry for `2015-01-01 01:05` with the precision of a minute. Queries are not really peformed as a range query with an `<` operator, rather entries are selected as blocks of a specified minute.

Range based queries succeed in a decent response time which is fine for me.

**Question:**
In the next step we want to gain additional informations by queries, which are mainly focused on the `IP` field. For example: select all the entries which have `IP1=xx.xx.xx.xx` and `IP2=yy.yy.yy.yy`.

So obviously the current model is pretty not usable for additional IP focused CQL queries. So the problem is not to find a possible solution, rather the various choices of possible technologies which could be a possible solution:

1. Try to solve the problem with standalone C* solutions. (Build a second model and administer the same data in a different shape)
2. Choose additional technologies like Spark...
3. Switch to HDFS/Hadoop - Cassandra/Hadoop solution...
4. and so on

With my lack of knowledge in this field, it is pretty hard to find the best way which i should take. Especially with the feeling that the usage of a cluster computing framework would be an excessive solution.

Comment: suggestions/recommendations are off-topic, but it's hard to vote-close a well formulated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood your question, your table schema looks like this:

```
create table logs (
  minute timestamp,
  id timeuuid,
  ips list<string>,
  message text,
  primary key (minute,id)
);
```

With this simple schema, you:

- can fetch all logs for a specific minute.
- can fetch short inter-minute ranges of log events.
- want to query dataset by IP.

From my point of view, there are multiple ways of implementing this idea:

- create secondary index on IP addresses. But in C* you will lose the ability to query by timestamp: C* cannot merge primary and secondary indexes (like mysql/pgsql).
- denormalize data. Write your log events to two tables at once, first being optimized for timestamp queries (minute+ts as PK), second being for IP-based queries (IP+ts as PK).
- use spark for *analytical* queries. But spark will need to perform (full?) table scan (in a nifty distributed map-reduce way, but nevertheless it's a table scan) each time to extract all the data you've requested, so all your queries will require a lot of time to finish. This way can cause problems if you plan to have a lot of low-latency queries.
- use external index like ElasticSearch for quering, and C* for storing the data.

For my opinion, the C* way of doing such things is to have a set of separate tables for different queries. It will give you an ability to perform blazing-fast queries (but with increased storage cost).

Comment: Thank you very much for this useful survey. Basically you catched all the issues and facts i've been worried about. As you already mentioned a secondary index is no option for me - unfortunately! I started playing around with Spark but you are right again: without a reasonable restriction i'll have to query the full table, which is no really good solution. Building a second model would be proper way to go, the problem: the amount of data and the short time period available for the writing process. Is there a native way to perform an insertion process in two different models simultaneously?

Comment: You can use [batched](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html) statements to write to two tables at the same time. Also these batches may behave like lightweight transactions if you use `LOGGED` batches.